# Abstract Class Method Header vs. Interface

Tags: java, interface, conventions, abstraction

I have 100 classes which extend an abstract class.

50 of these classes will need to have the method `foo()`, which varies among each class.

There are two ways to do this that I know of:

`Option #1`:
Create a single-method `interface` with `foo()`, and `implement` this `interface` in 50 of the classes.

`Option #2`:
Add an `abstract` method header `foo()` to the parent class, and leave the `foo()` method blank in 50 of the classes.

Which of these is a better convention and why? Or is there a better way I have not thought of?

Comment: sounds like half of your classes are actually some sub-type of your overall type. Perhaps multiple levels of inheritance is appropriate?

Comment: You can't leave an abstract method unimplemented in any concrete class. The best you could do would be to implement a default method (say, a no-op) in the base class. Does client code need to know about the `foo()` method?

Comment: Also 100 classes is a bit extreme; are you sure these even should be separate classes in the first place?

Comment: @Dave not literally 100 classes. I was just trying to keep my question as general as possible.  100 seemed like a nice round number and easy for people to see that it was 50/50(ish)

Comment: @Ted Hopp Just to make sure I understand, you are saying go the interface route?  Also, I am not sure what you mean by the client code...so no?

Comment: Use an interface when it is appropriate to do so. Use an abstract class when appropriate. And use both where appropriate (and I often do the last option).

Comment: I was pointing out that declaring an abstract method in the base class is not enough for the 50 classes that _don't_ implement `foo()`. In fact, whether you put in an abstract method or have the base class declared to implement an interface, you have the same problem. You can have 50 subclasses declared to implement the interface or (perhaps better), use Dave's idea (which dasblinkenlight made into an answer) of using an abstract subclass that will be the base class of the methods that need to implement `foo()`.

Comment: I disagree with closing this as an opinion-based question, because the two choices are not equivalent, and also because additional options exist.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - There are lots of options, but the question was "Which of these is a better convention and why?". Given the information available, the answer to that question is, in my view, entirely a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also a third option - create an abstract class that extends your base abstract class, and have the 50 classes extend that "intermediate" abstract class, like this:

```
abstract class Base {
    public abstract void bar();
}
abstract class BaseWithFoo extends Base {
    public abstract void foo();
}
class OneOfFiftyWithFoo extends BaseWithFoo {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        ... // Implementation
    }
}
```

I would use this approach if you need to share some common code among the fifty implementations of `foo`. In addition, it lets you write code that knows that an object has methods of `Base` *and* `BaseWithFoo`.

I would definitely *not* add `foo` to the `Base` abstract class, because it appears from your requirements that the method is not applicable to roughly half of your classes.

There are more parameters to consider.

- Does *every* class that extends the abstract class need `foo()`?

  - If no: not-functioning methods are ugly, go to step 3 or use an interface.
  - If yes: go to step 2.
- Does *every* subclass implement `foo()` the same way?

  - If yes: implement it in the superclass.
  - If no: go to step 3
- Are there bigger subsections of subclasses that can profit from a mutual implementation in another abstract subclass?

  - If yes: use intermediate abstract classes to implement functionality.
  - If no: direct the implementation of `foo()` to every subclass.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Is there a way to apply this if I have both foo1() and foo2() (or potentially more foo#()s)?  (This would make 4+ subclasses I think?)

Comment: I finished writing a little flowchart on the idea and I believe it fits together with your suggestion. I'll add it to your post but feel free to adjust/remove it if you disagree with an aspect.

Comment: A fourth option would be to declare an interface `Foo` for the method `foo()`, declare `BaseWithFoo` to `implements Foo`, and dispense with the abstract method.